# Angular 5 - use selected option in method

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular 5 and Angular Material for my application. 
I do have a select item with [value]="documentFileVersion".
My question now would be how I can access **documentFileVersion** at method **createPreview(documentFile, documentFileVersion)**.

```
<tr *ngFor="let documentFile of foundedDocumentFiles; index as i; let last = last">
    <td>
        <mat-form-field style="max-width:40px;">
           <mat-select>
               <mat-option *ngFor="let documentFileVersion of documentFile.documentFileVersions" [value]="documentFileVersion">
                           {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(8)}} - {{documentFileVersion.uploadTime}}
               </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </td>
    <td>
        <mat-icon class="icon-hover" (click)="createPreview(documentFile, documentFileVersion)">airplay</mat-icon>
    </td>
```

Comment: Seeing as that variable is created within an `ngFor`, there are several `documentFileVersion` (one for each option). Which instance is it you're interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `[(ngModel)]` and there by you can use it within the component.ts

```
<div>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let documentFileVersion of documentFile.documentFileVersions" [value]="documentFileVersion">
          {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(8)}} - {{documentFileVersion.uploadTime}}
        </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</div>
```

and use **`this.selected`** inside your method